# Upload image to server from windows phone 8.1 using windows.web.http

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

Iam currently working with windows phone 8.1 application.Iam really new to this
i want to know how to upload an image to webservice from windows phone 8.1 by using windows.web.http.Please help me i want the full details step by step.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
 Uri resourceAddress = new Uri("http://www.someurl.com/~?lalala");

 StorageFile img = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("ImageName.jpg");
 Stream inputStream = await img.OpenStreamForReadAsync();

 HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, resourceAddress);
 HttpMultipartContent cont = new HttpMultipartContent();
 cont.Add(new HttpStreamContent(inputStream.AsInputStream()));
 cont.Headers.ContentType = new HttpMediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
 request.Content = cont;
 request.Headers.Connection.Add(new HttpConnectionOptionHeaderValue("Keep-Alive"));
 request.Content.Headers.ContentLength = (ulong)inputStream.Length;


 HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendRequestAsync(request);

 if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Ok)
   {
      return true;
   }
```

or you can replace last "if" with:

```
 using (Stream responseStream = (await response.Content.ReadAsInputStreamAsync()).AsStreamForRead())
   {
      StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
      string result = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
   }
```

Here is good link with official samples on github: [HttpClient sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/HttpClient)

Comment: Is there any possibility for adding a get request after this post method

Comment: I have update answer. You can get response from server as string.